# iOS 11 bug, didselectrowatindexpath calls tapping at cell with two fingers simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios11, didselectrowatindexpath

The issue appeared with ios11. I have a usual screen with tableview, tapping on cell user goes to detail screen. I do not have  gesture recognizers at this screen. The steps next:
1) go to this screen with tableview
2) tap to cell, go to detail screen
3) then tap back
4) attempt to tap again on any cell, no actions
So didselectrowatindexpath calls only first time! Further investigation gave some result: 
didselectrowatindexpath calls only when you tap at cell with two fingers simultaneously!!! I can't explain this.
The same build works fine on ios10..
Any suggestions or somebody had the same issue ?

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt            indexPath: IndexPath) {
let timeReservations = currentReservations?.reservationsByTypes[indexPath.section]
let reservation = timeReservations?.reservations[indexPath.row]
let reservationMainVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
  Globals.ReservationMainVCConstants.identifier) as! ReservationMainViewController

reservationMainVC.reservationId = reservation?.id
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(reservationMainVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Comment: Where do you deselect the row?  Unless you deselect it, it will still be selected and you can’t select it again

Comment: @Paulw11 tried this, no success

Comment: @honcharenko13 , well i have the same issue, did you get any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this behavior was found. I use pod SwipeCellKit for creation  swipe actions. It blocks any actions on tableview. 
Link for this issue https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit/issues/92

to resolve this replace in your pod file  to

pod 'SwipeCellKit', :git =>     'https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit.git', :branch => 'master'

Comment: well i have the same issue, and i am using SwipeCellKit . Did you get any solution for the same, please let me know.